# Как вывести в определенном порядке, ориентируясь на значение ключа?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Как вывести в определенном порядке, ориентируясь на значение ключа? Например по значению ключа `drag`

```
    var list = '{"success":1,"content":{"content_count":2,"content_list":{"10":{"id":"10","title":"название 10","drag": "5"},"9":{"id":"9","title":"название 9","drag": "3"},"8":{"id":"8","title":"название 8","drag": "4"},"7":{"id":"7","title":"название 7", "drag": "1"},"6":{"id":"6","title":"название 6","drag": "2"}}}}';


    var obj = JSON.parse(list).content.content_list;
var search_result = "";
     Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
        // какой-то код
           search_result += '<p data-id="'+obj[key]['id']+'">'+obj[key]['title']+'</p>';
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var list = '{"success":1,"content":{"content_count":2,"content_list":{"10":{"id":"10","title":"название 10","drag": "5"},"9":{"id":"9","title":"название 9","drag": "3"},"8":{"id":"8","title":"название 8","drag": "4"},"7":{"id":"7","title":"название 7", "drag": "1"},"6":{"id":"6","title":"название 6","drag": "2"}}}}';


var obj = JSON.parse(list).content.content_list;
var search_result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){return obj[key]})
  .sort(function(a,b){return +a.drag-b.drag})
  .map(function(val){return '<p data-id="'+val.id+'">'+val.title+'</p>'})
  .join('');

console.log(search_result);
```

Comment: что-то не работает =(

Comment: Что не работает? У меня всё работает.

Comment: хотя нет не работает так

Comment: даже пример ваш не пашет {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Object.values is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 17,
  "colno": 28
}

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev с этого стоило начинать. Обновите свой браузер. Обновил ответ

Comment: пардон... заработало...